# Absolute center horizontal and vertical a div with fluid width and height?

Tags: html, css

how to make absolute center horizontal and vertical  a div with fluid width and height using css?
Thanks in advance for helping.

```css
#div_parent{
 background:#ccc;
 position:relative;
}

.div_child{
  background-color:#338BC7;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;  
  width: auto;
  height: auto; 
  padding: 20px;
  top:25%;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div  id="div_parent"> 
<div class="div_child">
 <p>Centered In The Middle Of The Page.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of problems with your code:

1. You do not have a `width` and `height` specified on your `html` and `body`, without which any of descendent elements wouldn't have a reference to set their positions and/or dimensions in percent units.
2. You do not have dimensions (width/height) specified on your `#div_parent`, without which you cannot position its absolutely positioned child (which is relative to it) to the vertical center. Moreover, as you want to position your `.div_child` to the center of the *page*, why do you have a parent wrapped around it anyway.

Apart from fixing the above, a trick which is usually used to align elements both horizontally and vertically is to use `transform: translate` to shift it back by `50%`.

Like this:

```
.div_child {
    position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    ...
}
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Lnqvqnkn/**

**Snippet:**

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; paddin:0; margin: 0; }
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
#div_parent{ height: 100%; width: 100%; background: #ccc; position: relative;}
.div_child {
    background-color: #338BC7;
    position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: auto; height: auto; 
    padding: 20px; color: white; text-align: center; border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div  id="div_parent"> 
  <div class="div_child">
 <p>Centered In The Middle Of The Page.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I want to display <div class="div_child"> like a popup which display horizontal and vertical centered of the browser window but without giving a fixed width and height.

Comment: @user3523031: In that case do not wrap it in a parent. That's it. Give whatever width/height you want (or not).

Comment: In IE browser div is not in center. i checked in ie9, ie 8 and ie7.

Answer (score 0):

When I need fluid width, I prefer using this method:

CSS

```
.background { display: table; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; }
.background > div { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; }
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <div>
    <p>Centered In The Middle Of The Page.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Demo on jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ilyabogdanov/q4rjbttq/)

Hope it works for you.